# Upload a folder?

Tags: ubuntu-one, directory, upload

I see that I can't synch a folder outside my home folder, but can upload a file that is outside my home folder. Can I upload a folder that is outside my home folder?

(I ask because I have a dual-boot system, with a parition for each OS and a third for my files, and it is these I want to synch)

Cheers!

Comment: You are lacking some information here. What are you using to do the synch? What do you mean by "upload"? Tell use what steps you are trying to achieve. Can you also give us a clue as to what folders outside of your home folder you are trying to use. Also, which OS's are you using in dual-boot?

Answer (score 1):

Like Julian said, what are you using to sync? I have a setup similar to yours. Kubuntu is my host OS, Win7 runs in a VM, and a partition stores my files (and "My Documents" for the Win7 VM.) I run Dropbox in the Kubuntu host to sync the "My Documents" partition.